# How to set up a Windows build slave to support Unity3D builds, without installing Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, msbuild, continuous-integration, packer

I need to set up Windows build agents (product isn't important) to build Unity3D projects.

I would *deeply* like to avoid installing Visual Studio (any version), since it is a large set of downloads during the build agent packer baking process, and takes a long time to actually process the installation, and invariably causes a reboot to be necessary which I then need to manage.

I'm aware it's possible to create offline installations; I want to avoid VS entirely, if it's unnecessary to the build.

I'm in this position because I'm unfamiliar enough with Unity3D to know whether VS is being installed "because that's what developers have on their workstations" (i.e. by accident of association), or because there's an actual dependency within it (like msbuild target files or what have you).

Is this possible? If so, what are the combinations of hopefully-smaller dependencies that are necessary to install? For example, Windows build tools, etc?

Comment: I'm not sure you need it at all. It's just an optional part of the Unity installation because MonoDevelop is... lacking. :)  They have their own version of Mono and such. You'll need the Android SDK for Android builds, and won't be able to do iOS builds because they do require Xcode, but otherwise you should be okay. As an example our build machines are Macs, no visual studio, and we make Windows builds on them just fine.

Comment: I'm concerned that on Windows, Unity may decide to not depend on mono for C# but instead expect msbuild and .NET libraries to exist and be installed.

I'll also be building on macOS (we make developer tooling), so there, I'm expecting this to be a bit easier since as you say, no need for VS (though I bet XCode will have its own set of foibles).

Comment: XCode is usually not too bad. You may have some issues with signing if you're planning to create build nodes on the fly. Automatic signing is picky the first time and you usually have to manually export a development and production ipa to get it to create the correct provisioning profiles. We do that on one machine and then copy them to all the rest which usually works, so you could archive then and copy them to any new nodes.

Comment: I'm expecting to store the necessary secrets within our hashicorp vault. So far, the Unity license management is the most fiddly bit...